# PKG: prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm pretty new to node and I just found the awesome [pkg project](https://github.com/vercel/pkg). It's been working great turning my javascript into .exe's until I included [`node-libcurl`](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl)

Here's the code that compiles:

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process')
const cheerio       = require("cheerio")

let link = "https://google.com"
const child      = spawnSync(`curl`, [link])
const html       = child.stdout
const HTMLobject = cheerio.load(html)
console.log(HTMLobject.html())
```

Here's the code that fails:

```js
const cheerio       = require("cheerio")
const { curly }     = require('node-libcurl')

let link = "https://google.com"
curly.get(link).then(request=>{
    const html = request.data
    const HTMLobject = cheerio.load(html)
    console.log(HTMLobject.html())
})
```

Here is the output of `$> pkg index.js` with errors:

```
> pkg@5.7.0
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
  node14-linux-x64, node14-macos-x64, node14-win-x64
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=v14.19.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=linux)
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=v14.19.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=v14.19.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
```

Why does it work for one script but not the other? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Created an issue on github: https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1662

Comment: The issue was made stale, if anyone is still having this issue, pls make a new issue on github, or comment and I'll post another too